# Access 2007 - How Do You Use VBA to Change Combobox Backcolor

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I want to change the BackColor of a combox box on a form using VBA.  I use this code:

```
Me.Combo1.BackColor=vbYellow
```

But the backcolor doesn't change.  I then put `DoEvents` after the above line but that didn't help. `Combo1.BackStyle` is set to Normal.  I noticed, however, that if I minimize the form and then restore it the backcolor changes to yellow.

Do I need to set the focus to a different control to make the change in backcolor take place?

Comment: Exactly where (in which procedure / handler) in the code are you putting the `Me.Combo1.BackColor = vbYellow` assignment? Who/what is calling that code and when?

Comment: I put it in a Command button procedure so I could test it out.  I have an event procedure: Sub Command1_Click

Answer (score 1):

You may have to repaint the form after the colour change:

```
Me.Repaint
```

and set *BackStyle* to Normal.

Comment: That didn't help.

Comment: Then either _BackStyle_ is set to transparent or something else is going on.